# GraphQL returning data using mongodb native driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I am trying return some data in graphiql using the mongodb native driver not mongoose. For some reason I don't get the data returned on graphiql. but when I console.log it I am able to see it.

Here is my Query

```
 type Highlight {
        id: ID!
        content: String!
        title: String
        author: String
    }    
    type Query {
        highlights: [Highlight]!
        highlight(id: ID!): Highlight
    }
```

Here is my resolver -

```
Query: {
    highlights: getHighlights,
}
```

Here is the getHighlights function -

```
async function getHighlights() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    const db = client.db(dbName);

    db.collection("highlights").find({})(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;     
      return result;
    });

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }
}
```

When I return this is what I see on graphiql
[image]

EDIT - 28/04/2021
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to return your data that you got from database,
you can see the error from grahql in `message` property:

```
async function getHighlights() {
  try {
    await client.connect();
    console.log("Connected correctly to server");
    const db = client.db(dbName);

    const data = db.collection("highlights").find({})(function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;     
      return result;
    });

    return data

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.stack);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error message on graphiql as above, but on console I am getting a different message which I will post to my original post.

Comment: I was able to figure it out. Thanks mohammed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/3826733/sumchans i'm glad i was able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. My issue was I'd misspelled one of the attribute names in the database. Quick one to check.